# ould not get unknown property 'VERSION_1_8' for object of type org.gradle.internal.extensibility.DefaultExtraPropertiesExtension

Tags: flutter

'''

'build.gradle'

'''

```
        ***
```

> ext{
> sourceCompatibility = VERSION_1_8
> targetCompatibility = VERSION_1_8
> defaultVersionName = flutterVersionName 1.0
> defaultVersionCode = flutterVersionCode.toInteger()***emphasized text***
> }
> buildscript {
> ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
> repositories {
> google()
> mavenCentral()
> }
>
> ```
>         dependencies {
>             classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4'
>             classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
>            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
>         }
>     }
>     
>     allprojects {
>         repositories {
>             google()
>             mavenCentral()
>         }
>     }
>     
>     rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
>     subprojects {
>         project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
>     }
>     subprojects {
>         project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
>     }
>     
>     task clean(type: Delete) {
>         delete rootProject.buildDir
>     }
> ```

---

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.